# Mobile friendly image

Tags: html, css, image, mobile

I have an image that is a link also at the top of my website, like a banner, and when I go on my mobile to look at it, it stays the same size. How do I make it smaller for mobile devices?

Comment: Does your site have a viewport set?

Comment: Yes a viewport is set

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rest of your website is responsive you can just add a width of 100% to the image.

So for example, if your image had a class of 'my-img'

```
.my-img {

  width:100%;
  max-width:600px;
  height:auto;

}
```

Or if you wanted to do it inline

```
<img src="" class="my-img" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;height:auto" />
```

Comment: So put a media queri of whatever pixels width and then say 100% width?

Comment: Yes exactly. Or, you could achieve the same thing without a media query by just setting width to 100% and max width to 600px or whatever you want the max to be on desktop

Answer (score 0):

probably it allready is responsive, even if you didn´t notice. you must have something like this in your code:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Yes that is in it, it's the logo at the top that doesn't resize

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Use Bootstrap js and Bootstrap CSS in that use media queries according to 
    screen 
 2. width do the coding or use class xs sm md lg.

# Mobile
only screen and (min-width: 480px)

# Tablet
only screen and (min-width: 768px) 

# Desktop
only screen and (min-width: 992px)

# Huge
only screen and (min-width: 1280px)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add media queries on your code like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #logo{
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       //in case you want a max-width-> max-width: 200px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have the following tag in your web-page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and then add image like following

```
<img src="your image path" alt="" class="heroImage">
    <style>
        .heroImage{width: 100%;max-width: 100%;}
    </style>
```

Comment: The css written in style tag you can write it in your external linked file.